# Has_many and collection_singular_ids with nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

For example

```
a=User.new
a.accounts_ids
# SELECT `accounts`.id FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`user_id` IS NULL
# So I have array with all not associated accounts WHY???
a.accounts.empty?
# true
a.accounts_ids << 124
a.accounts_ids
# [124]
a.accounts.empty?
# false
```

So why does Rails work so strangely? Why did I have a lot of accounts_ids when hadn't any accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when you do `Model.new`, rather than, say, `Model.create`, the resulting object (`a`, in your example) has all nil values, including it's id. `a.accounts_ids` looks for Account objects that have the `user_id` equal to `a.id`. Since that's still nil, it looks for ones that have nil `user_ids`.
Generally, the solution is to save the model (`User`, in your case) before messing about with it's associations.
So:

```
a = User.new
a.save
a.accounts_ids 
=> []
a.accounts.empty? 
=> true
```

This doesn't seem especially strange to me. As to the general question 'Why does Rails do X?', the answer is usually 'Because DHH and/or the Rails core team thought it should.'. Rails is a pretty opinionated framework. You do things its way, or be prepared to do a lot of extra work to do it any other way. [Convention over Configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) is the name of the game.

Comment: The problem is I have to arrays with accounts and with account ids (in fact account_ids == accounts.map{|a| a.id}). So it's rather logical to assume that if one is empty then the second is empty too. But this is not so. And I don't understand why rails made this way.

Comment: if `accounts_ids` is defined as `accounts.map{|a| a.id}`, then you may be quite sure that if accounts is empty, accounts_ids is also empty. If it's defined in some other way, maybe you should say how. I can't be sure, since you didn't include the definition, but it seems quite likely that you're doing something wrong here, rather than exposing irrational behavior on the part of Rails.

Comment: I mean that it seems rather strange, because ideological `accounts_ids` is smth like `accounts.map{|a| a.id}` however this is not true. And I don't understand why. Is it smth about caching of sql request or smth else?